# Pairing a bold geometric sans-serif with a light transitional sans-serif

Tags: font-pairing

I'm looking for a good heading typeface to pair with Numbus Sans Light body copy.  I tried a few modern and transitional serifs but I didn't really like them.  I think Futura PT Heavy would look good, but this is a violation of the "pair serifs with sans-serif" rule.

Do font pairs like this contrast enough to work well? (Main heading could also be normal caps or small caps)

[image: style guide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "pair serifs with sans-serif" rule is not almighty, it's just more likely to make things work because sans fonts will contrast more serifs. It is not guaranteed that it will look good.

What you've got here seems ok to me, I'm not super fond of it but there's enough contrast to distinguish both, not just considering the characters but also the weight, size, etc. I'm more worried by the lack of contrast between your navigation and your text but with a different color I'm pretty sure you would be fine.